# Change settings Prosilica camera Vimba C++

Tags: c++, camera, settings, ethernet

Currently I have working a prosilica ethernet camera (GC1020C) with API vimba in VS2010. I catch a frame, process it and iterate it.

I want change some camera settings. For example I want change the **EXPOSURE TIME**. Someone can help me with this task!?? I can't find a good documentation about this things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it!

```
res = m_pCamera->GetFeatureByName( "ExposureTimeAbs", featPtr );
featPtr->SetValue(EXPOSURE );
```